# How do I fetch data from subcollection in flutter, Im using firebase firestore. when I try to retrive the data from collections it works but sub no

Tags: firebase, flutter, collections

[My guests data looks like that becuase I wanted every detials to be under specific user, as you can see the useruid in the guests is the same with the userid in the users collection. and yet I can't fetch it. am i missing something? Note Im still new.

my code to fetch the data, it works with collection but not with sub collection.
Im trying to make to work with sub collection.

```
body: CustomScrollView(
slivers: [
SliverPersistentHeader(pinned: true, delegate: SearchBoxDelegate()),
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(

stream: Firestore.instance
.collection("Guests")
.orderBy("Date", descending: true).snapshots(),
builder: (context, dataSnapshot) {
return !dataSnapshot.hasData
? SliverToBoxAdapter(
    child: Center(
      child: circularProgress(),
    ),
  )
: SliverStaggeredGrid.countBuilder(
    crossAxisCount: 1,
    staggeredTileBuilder: (c) => StaggeredTile.fit(1),
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      ItemModel model = ItemModel.fromJson(
          dataSnapshot.data.documents[index].data);
      return sourceInfo(model, context);
    },
    itemCount: dataSnapshot.data.documents.length,
  );
},
),
],
),

Container(
child: Row(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Text(
        model.guestName,
        style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black, fontSize: 14.0),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
),
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZnuj.png)

Comment: I am not seeing any query for retrieving data from sub-collection in your code.

Comment: Firestore.instance
.collection("Guests")
.orderBy("Date", descending: true).snapshots(), what about this one?

Comment: same question I was tried by still not getting the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68442405/how-to-set-where-condition-on-array-of-reference-selection-in-flutter-using-clou